# Order by case statement in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, case-when

I have a parameter called `@Sorter` which passes an int (1 to sort it by a certain set of columns and 0 to sort it by another set of columns).

Within my dynamic SQL I get it to work when the user passes in 1 to that parameter when executing the procedure.

```
' ORDER BY CASE WHEN + ''' + @Sorter + ''' = 1 THEN l.List END ASC,
        ''Year'', ''MonthNum'' DESC, i.Item ASC'
```

The problem is when I try to add a case for when the parameter gets a value of 0 passed from the user, it starts complaining. Such as the following:

```
' ORDER BY CASE WHEN + ''' + @Sorter + ''' = 1 THEN l.List END ASC,
           CASE WHEN + ''' + @Sorter + ''' = 0 THEN ''Variance'' END ASC,
            ''Year'', ''MonthNum'' DESC, i.Item ASC'
```

The error is something about a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need extra case statements , try this:

```
' ORDER BY CASE ''' + cast(@Sorter as varchar(1))+ ''' WHEN '1' THEN l.List
                                WHEN '0' THEN ''Variance'' END ASC,
            ''Year'', ''MonthNum'' DESC, i.Item ASC'
```

Comment: sorry for the typo, remove the comma at the end of `l.list`

Comment: Thank you. I did not need to cast. What was happening with the constant error is that the column "variance" was being selected using the sum aggregate in the same query so I had to reference that sum aggregate in the case statement

Comment: you are welcome, glad to see the problem has solved, yes you don't need to cast and I guessed maybe the problem be from other parts of code, and I thought this(using one case statement) maybe useful, anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use one case when statement.

```
ORDER BY 
     (CASE WHEN + ''' + @Sorter + ''' = 1 THEN l.List
           WHEN + ''' + @Sorter + ''' = 0 THEN ''Variance'' END) ASC,
      ''Year'', ''MonthNum'' DESC, i.Item ASC'
```